# How to filter docs in MongoDB and then get one document ignoring duplicates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

So this is the schema of my document

```
"number" : 4657821598,
"hospitalID" : "mahaveer_bgm",
"value" : 1
```

first i would like to filter based on the **hospitalID** and then i want to remove all the duplicate for **number**.
 *for example* if there are 2 docs with same **number** after **hospitalID** filter   get me only the latest document.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

The below query applies the filter using `$match` followed by `$sort` on number desc and `$group` on number to pick the latest document.

`$$ROOT` to reference the whole document.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"hospitalID":"mahaveer_bgm"}},
  {"$sort":{"number":-1},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$number",
    "name":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly